# Where the HTTP server 'localhost:8080' is located?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Im trying to play song in my app like this

```
var audio = new Audio('../songs/1.mp3')
```

`audio.play()`

My `songs` folder is located in `dist`, but its wrong location, because `audio.src` gets the next value `http://localhost/songs/1.mp3`.
So how do I know where this server is located?

Comment: in dev mode is located in public folder but in production it will be in dist folder

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim, yeap i'm talking about dev mode. What you mean public folder?

Comment: in vue cli 3 the folder named public is used to in dev mode

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim, Im not using vue cli

Comment: what are you using?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim, vuex, webpack,     "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",